# Set up Windows 10 as a VPN server with DNS resolution

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn, dns

I want to be able to connect to my private domains remotely. To that end, I've set up a VPN server on my Windows 10 machine, following https://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/. However, running `netstat -ano | findstr ":1723"` returns no results, regardless of whether the firewall is on or off. There is no other security software I'm aware of that could be blocking the Routing and Remote Access service, which is running.

What else can I try?

<s>I'm trying to set up my Windows 10 machine to be a VPN server with DNS. I've been trying on Windows XP too. These are my goals:</s>

1. Set up a VPN server (done (apparently))
2. Connect to the VPN server internally (fails for Windows 10, works for XP)
3. Connect to the VPN server externally (the VPN rules in the router firewall don't seem to work)
4. Resolve internal private domain names to IPs and be able to connect to them (DNS lookup seems totally broken when connected to XP's VPN, the DNS server is 0.0.0.0)
5. Use the VPN connection only for private addresses and use the regular connection for all other internet addresses (I think this depends on how many active network connections you can have. I know Windows allows multiple, but it seems Android only allows one at a time)

If I can do all these things, I will be able to connect to my VPN when I choose, and access domains on my private network. When I'm browsing, only my local addresses will be uploaded by my VPN, other addresses will be downloaded directly, preventing doubling of data usage.

So far, I've been able to set up the VPN on Windows 10 but not connect to it, even internally. When I try to connect, it waits for about a minute, then says it fails. When I tried to connect my old XP machine to it, I got an `Error 800`.

Strangely, when I set up a VPN server on my XP machine (as a troubleshooting step), both the Windows 10 machine and my Android phone were able to connect to it internally, but without DNS. I could connect to resources on it via the machine's IP address only, none of its domain names would resolve.

Just to be clear, both my Android phone and Windows 10 can connect to my Windows XP machine's VPN. Neither my Android phone nor Windows XP can connect to my Windows 10 machine's VPN.

I made sure that the Routing and Remote Access service is running on Windows 10. I used this guide https://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software/ to set up Windows 10.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with just what comes with Windows 10, or will I have to download a different VPN server or use an external VPN service?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Yes, that's exactly the guide I followed. Is that the problem? ;-P

Comment: LOL, I don't think so! Have you disabled all firewalls and security software when trying to connect from another device on your LAN? Error 800 often occurs when some of the traffic needed to establish the VPN is being blocked.

Comment: Oddly, when I disabled Windows 10's firewall, it failed much faster, although with the same error message.

Comment: you have no other security software on the box? Nothing running on the other machine that might block anything? PPTP VPNs only use port 1723, but in addition to the IP protocol they use the GRE protocol which when blocked usually causes that 800 error.

Comment: You can also check to confirm a process is listening on port 1723 on the Win 10 box by running the command `netstat -ano | findstr ":1723"`

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Nope, Windows 10 is pretty vanilla. It's got less security than XP which slightly works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73641/discussion-between-cj-dennis-and-twisty-impersonator).

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I restarted the RRAS based on some information on other sites, and now it works (although I can't log in)!